# Use PHP on Mac OS X to Create DOS-format Text File for Bing Product Feed

Tags: php, macos, line-endings

I want to use a php script that already process my google product feed to also create a bing product feed, which should just be a tab delimited text file... So far, I can only get bing to recognize "2" columns in the file when tested. I suspect it is due to their requiring a utf-8 encoded "DOS formatted" text file. So far I have this:

Open file for feed:

```
$bing = fopen('bing_products.txt','ab');
```

Create header row:

```
$header_row="MPID       Title   BrandorManufacturer     MerchantSKU     ProductURL      Price   StockStatus     Description     ImageURL        BingCategory    Condition\r\n";
```

Loop through products:

```
$bing_text.=bing_simpl($item_number)."      ";
$bing_text.=bing_simpl($name." color ".substr($item_number, 3,4)." size ".$unit_of_measure)."       ";
$bing_text.=bing_simpl($manufacturer)."     ";
$bing_text.=bing_simpl($item_number)."      ";           $bing_text.="https://example.com/".$general_category."/".strtolower($item_no_three)."       ";
$bing_text.=number_format($price_one,2)."   ";
$bing_text.="In Stock       ";
$bing_text.=bing_simpl($descript." color ".substr($item_number, 3,4)." size ".$unit_of_measure)."   ";
$bing_text.=$image_url."    ";
$bing_text.=$general_category.">".simpl($craft).">".simpl($key_word_i)."    ";
$bing_text.= "New\r\n";
```

Write and close file:

```
fwrite($bing, $header_row.$bing_text);fclose($bing);
```

Optionally add UTF-8 bytecode:

```
$str=file_get_contents('bing_products.txt');
file_put_contents('bing_products.txt',"\xEF\xBB\xBF".$str);
```

"bing_simpl" and "canonical_name" strip any extraneous formatting. I've tried it using "\t" for tabs. I've tried it without the file_get_contents / file_put_contents... Testing the file for encoding with PHP returns ASCII (it should indeed be UTF-8, I'm processing an exported xml file form FileMaker).

Am I missing something simple?

[UPDATE]
It appears that part of the issue is with using either gzip, or finder's "compress" functions to compress the feed file. I.E. I can get a truncated, uncompressed version of the file to work ok (has to be small enough to work with bing's "test" form). Will update if I'm able to find a work-around to use compressed versions.

Comment: I think using \t for tabs was the correct thing to do. Can you look at your bing_products.txt file with a raw text editor like bbEdit? If you do, Show Invisibles, and see if the file looks to be correctly formatted.

Comment: thanks, I'll try again with \t... I looked in bbEdit, and it shows tab and line endings. Also, VIM shows the tabs/line endings, and returns filefomat=dos for "set ff?"...

Comment: ugh, switching back to \t didn't work, nor did showing invisibles in VIM and copying the ^I character from a working example file...

Answer (score 0):

Bing Products already support Google Shopping seamlessly. http://www.cpcstrategy.com/blog/2014/04/google-feed-for-bing-shopping-product-ads/

If you have access to a Windows machine, you could create a bingproducts.txt file using Notepad and examine the headers and tab newline characters in vim?

Comment: Thanks, I tried importing my Google Shopping feed, but didn't have any luck. In the article it mentions that the new Google Shopping campaigns wouldn't transfer after August 2014, I'm wondering if there was a drop in support for importing feeds too? I'll try today to open up my bing file in Notepad - [unfortunately in this case] we're all mac at work...